# Drupal Multiline Title

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, cck

At the moment I may have a title like

**Welcome to my new Website made using Drupal**

This title is splitting onto two lines but I have no control where the break takes place.

I would much rather have:

**Welcome to my new Website**

**made using Drupal**

To do this I decided the best thing to do is to create a new CCK field to house the title and insert a 
 into it.

I will leave the normal title there and fill it in as well so it appears in the title bar correctly and in the search results etc.

I can get my custom cck field(text) using the following code in my theme:

```
<?php print $node->field_page_title[0]['safe'] ?>
```

The problem is that this is coming across as

```
<p>Welcome to my new Website<br /> made using Drupal</p>
```

I need to strip the p tags away. I can do this in the theme layer but to  me it would make more sense to do it in a module because there will not be a situation where I would want the

tags.

What hook would I need to use to change this. Do you think I am going about this in the best way?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you insert the `<br />` tag in the node title and allow it in your theme.

Comment: IS that the return character?